# Execution plan using B+ tree index, but also sorts

Tags: oracle-11g, sqlplus, execution-plan, explain, sorting

I'm using Oracle `sqlplus`. And I have the following query:

```
SELECT fooID from foo MINUS
SELECT fooID from bar;
```

I have created two unclustered B+ tree indexes. One in the field `fooID`of the table `foo` and one in the field `fooID` of the table `bar`. After that I analyze the statistics of both my tables: `foo` and `bar` and check the execution plan of my query using `EXPLAIN PLAN ...`. But I get this:

```
  SELECT STATEMENT
      MINUS
        SORT UNIQUE
          INDEX FAST FULL SCAN FOO_INDEX
        SORT UNIQUE
          INDEX FAST FULL SCAN BAR_INDEX
```

How is that even possible? When doing `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN`, because the index is a B+ tree, doesn't the system gets back it's tuples sorted? Why does it need to do `SORT UNIQUE` (data already sorted)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle says about [Indexes and Index-Organized Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm#autoId8) under **Full Index Scan**: In a full index scan, the database reads the entire index *in order*.

Yet, unter **Fast Full Index Scan**, it reads: A fast full index scan is a full index scan in which the database accesses the data in the index itself without accessing the table, and the database reads the index blocks in *no particular order*. (Emphasis mine)

Now, probably, the question should be: why did the optimzier choose `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` over `INDEX FULL SCAN`.

A hint to the answer of the latter question is given in  under **11.2.3.7 Fast Full Index Scans**:  A fast full scan *is faster* than a normal full index scan because it can use multiblock I/O and can run in parallel just like a table scan.

If you insist that Oracle use a *full index scan*, you might want to try the `/*+ index() */` hint:

```
create table tq84_foo (
  fooID number not null
);

create table tq84_bar (
  fooID number not null
);

create unique index ix_foo on tq84_foo(fooID);
create unique index ix_bar on tq84_bar(fooID);

explain plan for
 select /*+ index(f ix_foo) */fooID from tq84_foo f
        MINUS
select /*+ index(b ix_bar) */ fooID from tq84_bar b;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

resulting in

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |        |     1 |    26 |     4  (75)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MINUS              |        |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   SORT UNIQUE NOSORT|        |     1 |    13 |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN  | IX_FOO |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |   SORT UNIQUE NOSORT|        |     1 |    13 |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    INDEX FULL SCAN  | IX_BAR |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```